# How to pass data fromC# to Microsoft excel?

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I am looking for a program that sends the data from C# windows form to Microsoft Excel and also plot these data in a x-y line graph!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        double t2 = 20;
        int t1 = 10;
        int i, j;
        double []s= new double[10];


 for (i = 0; i <= t1; i++)
 {
 for (j = 0; j <= t2; j++)
 {

      xlWorkSheet.Cells[(i+1), (j+1)] = s[(j / 2)];

     Excel.Range chartRange;

     Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
     Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(100, 80, 300, 250);

     Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

     chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "Z10");

     j += 1;
     chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);

     chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterSmooth;

  }
}

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("link1.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
```

U can modify the code accordingly!!

Comment: ya! i will do that thank u for helping me out!